# swift's ternary operator confusion with optionals

Tags: swift, option-type, ternary-operator

is there a way to get the ternary operator to work in this sample code?

```
var arr: [Int] = [4,3,2,1]

var o = ""
for i in stride(from: arr.count - 1, through: 0, by: -1) {
    o = o + String(arr[i]) + (i > 0? " " : "")
}
```

swift tells me...

> Cannot use optional chaining on non-optional value of type 'Int'

thanks

Comment: You need at least one whitespace between `0` and `?`.

Comment: OMG! I feel do silly!!!  Thank you.